# documentChanges contains unopened files get error: bad edit - model not found

Tags: monaco-editor, language-server-protocol

- monaco-editor@0.41.0
- monaco-languageclient@6.4.6
  I recently encountered an issue whilst using the ‘rename symbol’ feature on Monaco Editor. The problem arises specifically when trying to rename symbols for files that have not been opened. In this scenario, an error returns stating 'bad edit - model not found’.
  As I understand it, the issue stems from the fact that Monaco does not create a model for unopened files. As a result, it can’t apply an edit. This process seems to work fine for opened files as I am able to rename symbols without any issues.
  My question is - what would be the best way to handle changes to unopened files? Is there a way to create a model for files that haven’t been opened yet or is there an alternative solution for dealing with this situation?
  Any assistance or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
  Thank you for your time and consideration.
  Best Regards.

No error will be reported and is there any way to change a file that is not open